# Two same javascript code behaving in different way(In different browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form with name `frmOrderReschedule` and an hidden element `frmOrderReschedule`.
i tried to access it in this way-

```
document.frmOrderReschedule.newSalesOrderNumber.length
```

it gave me error document.frmOrderReschedule.newSalesOrderNumber.length is `undefined`, but when i try in fallowing way it works properly

```
document.getElementsByName('newSalesOrderNumber').length;
```

this is happening in Mozila only.Any one can throw some light on it, why it's happenning like this.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What does `document.frmOrderReschedule.newSalesOrderNumber` return? What kind of element is `newSalesOrderNumber`? How many are there actually? Can you show the HTML? BTW, you should avoid DOM 0 access of form elements as in your first example. `document.forms["frmOrderReschedule"].elements["newSalesOrderNumber"]`is better and more readable.

Comment: `document.frmOrderReschedule.newSalesOrderNumber` is hidden element,it can be multiple depending upon requirement

Comment: i have only one form in my page that's why i have used first example

Comment: If you have only one input with this name, just give it ID and use `document.getElementById("newSalesOrderNumber")` instead - this is most efficient way. To check the length of the *value* use `document.getElementById("newSalesOrderNumber").value.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your comment I deduct, that the field can be present one or multiple times. In that case  `document.frmOrderReschedule.newSalesOrderNumber` (or `document.forms["frmOrderReschedule"].elements["newSalesOrderNumber"]`) can return different types.

If there are multiple controls, it will return a collection, which will have a `length` property. If there is only one control, then it will return a direct reference to that control, which - obviously - doesn't have a length. That means, if you use that syntax you need to distinguish between the two variants (or even three variant, in case the field isn't there):

```
var x = document.forms["frmOrderReschedule"].elements["newSalesOrderNumber"];
if (x) {
    if (x.length) {
        alert("There are " + x.length + " controls.")
    } else {
        alert("One control with value: " + x.value);
    }
} else {
    alert("None");
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/H4Lks/1/

`document.getElementsByName('newSalesOrderNumber')` on the other hand **always** returns a collection, even if there are none or one, so it always has a `length`.